# After Effects: Create Text inside Shape layer

Tags: after-effects, compositing, motion-graphics

Hello you beautiful people. I am trying to create a shape made out of text. I thus need the text layer to set its bounding box to the path of my animated shape, instead of a simple box. I cannot simply mask the text, as no letter should be cut off. Do you have any idea how I may achieve this? I haven't found anything online so far...

Comment: Since there's no control for the bounding box, you can't use an expression. You could script it, I think.